# xpath: How do I extract text within the "strong" tag?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and need to extract "Gray / Gray" using xpath selectors.
Here's the html snippet:

```
<div class="Vehicle-Overview">
    <div class="Txt-YMM">
        2006 GMC Sierra 1500
    </div>
    <div class="Txt-Price">
        Price :                                     $8,499
    </div>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
    class="Table-Specs">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>2006 GMC Sierra 1500 Crew Cab 143.5 WB 4WD 
                SLE</strong>
                <strong class="text-right t-none"></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Gray / Gray</strong><br />
                <strong>209,123 
                            Miles

                                  / VIN: XXXXXXXXXX

            </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

I'm stuck trying to extract "Gray / Gray" within the "strong" tag. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath will work in Scrapy and also in Google/Firefox Developer's Console:

```
//div[@class='Vehicle-Overview']/table[@class='Table-Specs']//tr[2]/td[1]/strong[1]/text()
```

You can use this code in your spider:

```
color = response.xpath("//div[@class='Vehicle-Overview']/table[@class='Table-Specs']//tr[2]/td[1]/strong[1]/text()").extract_first()
```

Comment: This worked! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath expression with your sample XML/HTML:

```
//div[@class='Vehicle-Overview']/table[@class='Table-Specs']/tr[2]/td[1]/strong[1]
```

A full XPath given the full file mentioned below with respect to a namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" can be

```
/html/body/div/div/div[@class='content-bg']/div/div/div[@class='Vehicle-Overview']/table[@class='Table-Specs']/tr[2]/td[1]/strong[1]
```

Comment: Here is the page from which I'm trying to extract the color: https://www.niceneasyautosales.com/inventory/view/10769329/2006-GMC-Sierra-1500-Crew-Cab-143.5-WB-4WD-SLE-Arlington-TX

Comment: The above xpath doesn't extract "Gray/Gray"

Comment: this selects the strong tag element, but how do i extract text within the tag?

Comment: Try adding `/text()` to the end of the XPath. Usually that's implied.

Comment: In this case, if you add /text() to the end, it returns empty since there is no text after the strong tag.